# How do I call a stored procedure from NHibernate that has a result using C#?

Tags: c#-3.0

I have a stored procedure that loads data and returns on record in a string format. How do I call it and capture the result using NHibernate

Eg below

````
var query = session.CreateSQLQuery("EXECUTE LoadData @ActualsDate =:ActualsDate, ActualBroadcastMonth =:ActualsMonth")
.SetTimeout(0)
.SetParameter("ActualsDate", actualsDate)
.SetParameter("ActualsMonth", actualsMonth)
.???;
return ...;```
````

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer

```
.SetTimeout(0)
.SetParameter("ActualsDate", actualsDate)
.SetParameter("ActualsMonth", actualsMonth)
.UniqueResult;
return query.ToString();
```